# Preposition choice for some applying method/way/procedure?

Tags: word-choice

Let say I have `Z` representing a *method* or *procedure*. I want this `Z` which is naturally a *`noun`* (because it's a method) to act as it is a *`verb`*. For example

[image]

Now say, I want this *`Z`* to be applied to *`A`*. In other words I want it to be:

> *Do or apply Z to/on/for A*

In that case, what would be the preposition I take?

- Note that It doesn't need  to be academical (For example, you might say to highlight an arrow direction, your flowchart/figure should be in a certain order, etc.), what I want is simply, a right preprosition.

Comment: Can you provide an example with actual nouns instead of letter placeholders? And/or some context -are you specifying a computer language algorithm, describing a cooking recipe, or what?

Comment: We generally ***apply*** something ***to*** something else.

Comment: You should avoid variables. They are not words and this isn't Math SE.

Comment: Normally a method accepts inputs.  The method *acts upon* those inputs. We *invoke* or *call* the method, supplying the required input(s) or required parameter(s).